# Running last in awk [Solaris]

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, solaris

How can i run `last` command for every matched line in awk?

```
ypcat passwd | awk -F":" '/:John / { system("last" $1)  }'
```

I'm trying to execute the `last` command for every user that is named John but It does not print anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, awk is not shell. awk is designed to manipulate text not to call other tools from, that is what a shell is for This may be what you want, depending on what `last` is/does:

```
ypcat passwd | awk -F":" '/:John /{print $1}' | xargs last
```

or:

```
ypcat passwd | awk -F":" '/:John /{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 last
```

Answer (score 4):

Insert a whitespace after `last`:

```
ypcat passwd | awk -F":" '/:John / {system("last " $1)}'
```